# Is it necessary to delete a pointer after setting it with an address?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address, delete-operator

I have class called input.
If I had 2 Variables

`Input inp;`
and

`Input* inp2;`

and I did something like this.

`inp2 = &inp;`

Would it be necessary to delete this pointer using `delete inp`

When I tried to delete it in my application

I got a runtime error so I'm not sure whats going on here.

Comment: `inp` is not a pointer in your example; `inp2` is.

Comment: You `delete` only when you (or some library) allocates memory with `new`. There is no `new` in your example, so you do not `delete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be necessary to delete this pointer using delete inp

First, you mean delete a variable being pointed to, not a pointer ( pointer is put on stack and will go out of scope sooner or later), so

```
delete inp2
```

Second - No. You only call `delete` on a variable that was allocated with `new`.

> Because the default version of operator new is a general-purpose
>   allocator, it must be prepared to allocate blocks of any size.
>   Similarly, the **default version of operator delete must be prepared to**
>   **deallocate blocks of whatever size operator new allocated**. For
>   operator delete to know how much memory to deallocate, it must have
>   some way of knowing how much memory operator new allocated in the
>   first place. A common way for operator new to tell operator delete how
>   much memory it allocated is by prepending to the memory it returns
>   some additional data that specifies the size of the allocated block.

`operator delete` needs the information created by `operator new`

Answer (score 3):

Any heap memory allocation (like `new` and `malloc`) should be eventually freed by `delete` / `free`.

`Free` and `Delete` should NOT be used for any other addresses.

Comment: Best not to mix `new/malloc` and `delete/free`

Comment: Also, heap allocation functions are not always obvious:  `alloca` does not allocate from the heap, despite its "alloc-name", while `strdup` does allocate.

Answer (score 2):

Does this actually compile.

You only use `delete` when you use `new`. Ditto for `delete[]` when you have used `new[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider

```
int inp = 1;
int *inp2 = &inp;
```

Here both inp  and inp2 are stack variables having automatic storage duration and will go out of scope at the end of the current compound statement / function ...

If you set / reset the value of `inp2` i.e.

```
int inp = 1;
int *inp2 = &inp;
int inp3 = 3;
inp2 = &inp3;
```

you don't do anything different than reassigning any fundamental type. You only change the value of a local variable (of type `int*`).
There is no manual / dynamic memory allocation going on.

`delete` is used to free memory (allocated using `new`) and must be applied to a pointer, pointing to a memory location which has been allocated using `new`.

```
int * inp4 = new int;
// ...
delete inp4;
```

Answer (score -1):

use free() to delete it as you are allocating memory to it statically delete is for dynamic memory allocation malloc calloc etc